# My Win32 dialog is not receiving WM_GETOBJECT with lParam set to OBJID_CLIENT

Tags: winapi, dialog, accessibility, win32gui, wtl

I've written a custom control (that does not create an `HWND`) that sits inside a modal dialog. I'm trying to intercept `WM_GETOBJECT` with `lParam` set to `OBJID_CLIENT` so I can return my `IAccessible` implementation of my custom control. The strange thing is I never see `lParam` set to `OBJID_CLIENT` although I do see `WM_GETOBJECT`.

The dialog is derived from WTL's `CDialogImpl`

The strange thing is, if I create a child window of the dialog and size it to fit within the dialog's client area, THAT window DOES get `WM_GETOBJECT` with `lParam` set to `OBJID_CLIENT` and everything works correctly.

Is there some special style or property I need to set on the dialog to receive the correct `WM_GETOBJECT` calls?

Comment: What does "not based on an `HWND`" mean?

Comment: Meaning it does not instantiate an HWND via CreateWindow. It's just an object that can render itself to a dc

Comment: You say you are getting `WM_GETOBJECT`, just not `OBJID_CLIENT`, so what value(s) ARE you getting? Your control does not have an `HWND` so it cannot receive `WM_GETOBJECT` directly, you have to process it from the dialog's `HWND` instead. Seems like you would need a custom `IAccessible` for the dialog itself that reports your control as a child of the dialog. Do you have that? Or is that what you are having trouble implementing?

Comment: It might be easier just to wrap your control in a "do-nothing" window class that can receive its own `WM_GETOBJECT` messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the lParam is either 0 or -25 (which doesn't seem to even be a valid value). I am checking for WM_GETOBJECT in the dialog's windowproc. The dialog is itself a window of course which should have support for IAccessible for itself at least.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That was one solution I tried but that would mean all my handling of mouse move/click messages that my custom control needs would have to be forwarded from the "do-nothing" window. Seems like a bit of a hack. Perhaps modal dialogs just don't ever receive the IAccessible notification directly. Although that seems to be false because running "Inspect" shows the dialog, the caption toolbar and the close button all as accessible objects

Comment: You could try sub-classing the dialog and see if you get the expected `WM_GETOBJECT` messages that way - it may be that the dialog manager is filtering them out and not forwarding them to the dialog procedure.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Like overwriting the window proc with SetWindowLongPtr?

Comment: @cppguy Prefer `SetWindowSubclass`.

Comment: @cppguy: -25 is `UiaRootObjectId`, which means "*the request is for a UI Automation provider. If the server is implementing UI Automation, it should return a provider using the [UiaReturnRawElementProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684069.aspx) function.*". See [Handling the WM_GETOBJECT Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd561885.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Active Accessibility has built in support for dialogs, so it may not be sending OBJID_CLIENT. Also I'm not sure if you can create your own custom IAccessible object for the dialog that has your fake control as a child since dialog objects don't support `get_accChild`. Instead clients are supposed to "obtain the window handle of the control and then call AccessibleObjectFromWindow". I think you could save yourself a lot grief by implementing your control in a window like normal.

Answer (score 1):

So, ultimately I solved this problem by creating a child window at the same position as my custom control in my dialog with `WM_ERASEBKGND` returning `TRUE` and `WM_NCHITTEST` returning `HTTRANSPARENT`. In the message map of that window I forward all `WM_GETOBJECT` messages to my custom control.